# Cannot extract label from form to translate

Tags: symfony

Im using JMS Translation Bundle to extract, and below is my setting:

jms_i18n_routing:

```
    default_locale: %locale%
    locales: [en]
    strategy: prefix_except_default

jms_translation:
    configs:
        app:
            dirs: [%kernel.root_dir%, %kernel.root_dir%/../src]
            output_dir: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/translations
            ignored_domains: [routes]
            excluded_names: [*TestCase.php, *Test.php]
            excluded_dirs: [cache, data, logs]
#            extractors: [jms_translation.file_visitor]
```

however, it seems to not able to pickup and form label from my bundle when run:

> php app/console translation:extract de --dir=./src/
>   --output-dir=./app/Resources/translations

And my form looks like this

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name', 'text', array(
            'label' => 'nilead.form.discount.name'
        ))

            ->add('value', 'number', array(
                'label' => 'nilead.form.discount.number',
                'constraints' => array(
                    new GreaterThan(array('value' => 0))
                )
            ))

            ->add('percentage', 'percent', array(
                'label' => 'nilead.form.discount.percentage',
            ))

            ->add('code', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'nilead.form.discount.code',
            ))

            ->add('throughDate', 'date', array(
                'label' => 'nilead.form.discount.throughDate',
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
            ))

            ->add('fromDate', 'date', array(
                'label' => 'nilead.form.discount.fromDate',
                'widget' => 'single_text',
                'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd',
            ))

            ->add('usageRemaining', 'text', array(
                'label' => 'nilead.form.discount.usageRemaining',
            ))

            //->add('fromDate', 'text')

//            ->add('throughDate', 'text')

            ->add('calculator', 'nilead_discount_calculator_choice', array(
                'empty_value' => '----',
                'label' => 'nilead.form.discount.calculator',
            ))
            ->addEventSubscriber(new BuildDiscountFormListener($this->calculator, $builder->getFormFactory()));

        $prototypes = array();
        $prototypes['calculators'] = array();

        foreach ($this->calculator->getCalculators() as $calculator) {
            $calculatorObj = $this->calculator->get($calculator);
            $prototype = $builder->create('settings', $calculatorObj->getConfigurationFormType())->getForm();

            $prototypes['calculators'][$calculator] = $prototype;
        }
        $builder->setAttribute('prototypes', $prototypes);
    }
```

Comment: did you clear your cache? :) you have already configured a configuration named "app" - you should use `php app/console translation:extract de --config=app` to extract your translations.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work now. It just doesnt seem to automatically put the trans into MyBundle.en.xliff but it puts to messages.en.xliff instead. IS there anyway I can make it auto detect namespaces and put into the correct ones?

Comment: Those aren't namespaces but socalled [translation/message domains](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html#using-message-domains) ... you can set the message domain either in your configuration as `domain: [messagedomain]` ( note that you can have multiple configurations ) or by appending `--domain=domainname` to the console extract-command as far as i remember :) ... and i'm pretty sure the domain gets extracted if you specify it in twig aswell.

Comment: thanks a lot nifr. Can you please put your answer as an "answer" so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use translator service, like this:

```
$translator = $this->get('translator');
$translator->trans('nilead.form.discount.number', array(), 'SomeBundle');
```

Before this - inject translator to your form using DI.

Comment: You can pass translator service to the constructor during object creation

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [JMSTranslationBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSTranslationBundle) to extract labels etc from forms to the translation files:

**Example:**

```
$ bin/console translation:extract --output-dir translations/ -d src/Form en
```